# Ruby make 2 different constructors with same ammount of parameters

Tags: ruby, class, constructor

I've got a class just like this:

```
class Equipment

    attr_reader :text
    attr_reader :name
    attr_reader :array1
    attr_reader :number

end
```

then, I want to make 2 constructors with 3 parameters each:

1º one -> (text,name,array1)

2º one -> (text, name,number)

The first one as an argument has an array and the other one has an integer (1,2...), so I need to define both constructors so when I create an object of this class it makes a difference between array or integer as the 3º argument.

Any ideas?

EDIT.: I thought this:

```
def initialize(text = "", name = "", array = array.new, number =0)

    @text = text
    @name = name
    @array1 = array
    @number = number

end
```

(initializing all of them) then:

```
def Equipment.newc_witharray(sometext, somename, somearray)

    @text = sometext
    @name = somename
    @array1 = somearray

end

def Equipment.newc_withint(sometext, somename, somenumber)

    @text = text
    @name = name
    @number = somenumber

end
```

and finally calling objects like this:

```
character1 = Equipment.newc_withint("Barbarian", "conan", 3)
```

shouldn't this work?

Comment: Class names are constants and thus have to start with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create as many constructors as you want on the class with whatever name you want. There is one constructor `new`, which is inherited from `Object`, and that can be used to write other constructors. What other answers mention as the constructor, namely the instance method `initialize` is not a constructor. That is the method called by the constructor method `new` by default.

```
class Foo
  def self.new1 text, name, array1
    obj = new
    # do something on obj with text, name, array1
    obj
  end
  def self.new2 text, name, number
    obj = new
    # do something on obj with text, name, number
    obj
  end
end

Foo.new1(text, name, array1)
Foo.new2(text, name, number)
```

Comment: I don't understand what to do with this line:     obj = new

Comment: Nothing to add to `obj = new`. And do instance variable assignments in the context of `obj` after that.

Comment: Aren't neccesary parenthesis in def self.new1 (yadda, yadda,...)?

Comment: Although I think Ruby can do better than this, perhaps now rename these methods to something more descriptive like `from_number` and `from_array`.

Comment: `konstructor` gem allows to add extra constructors to the class with one word declarations

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this.

#### Hash arguments

You could pass a hash and extract the values you're interested in:

```
def initialize(options={})
  @text = options.fetch(:text)        # raises KeyError if :text is missing
  @name = options.fetch(:name)        # raises KeyError if :name is missing
  @array = options.fetch(:array, [])  # returns [] if :array is missing
  @number = options.fetch(:number, 0) # returns 0 if :number is missing
end
```

#### Keyword arguments

In Ruby 2.0 you can use [keyword arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) with default values:

```
def initialize(text: text, name: name, array: [], number: 0)
  @text = text
  @name = name
  @array = array
  @number = number
end
```

#### Switching on argument type

This makes the method harder to read, but would work, too:

```
def initialize(text, name, number_or_array)
  @text = text
  @name = name
  @number = 0
  @array = []
  case number_or_array
  when Integer then @number = number_or_array
  when Array then @array = number_or_array
  else
    raise TypeError, "number_or_array must be a number or an array"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Built into the language, no, Ruby does not give you that ability.

However, if you want that ability, I would create an `initialize` method which takes a hash as its parameter.  Then you could create an instance of the class using any number of parameters.

E.g:

```
class Equipment
  attr_reader :text, :name, :array1, :number

  def initialize(options)
    [:text, :name, :array1, :number].each do |sym|
      self.send(sym) = options[sum]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess we all got downvoted for no reason.

Comment: @KepaniHaole: which is sad, because then we don't know how to improve the answer or what was wrong with the answer.:(

Comment: I didn't do it!! but @Sawa 's answer is what I'm looking for! Thank you both of you since this instructed me as well :)

Comment: @Zasito: make sure you mark Sawa's answer as correct, then.:)

Answer (score 0):

The ruby interpreter wouldn't be able to differentiate between the constructors, as the types are not known until runtime :(

However, you can use a very nice workaround:

```
class Foobar
  def initialize(h)  # <-- h is a hash
    # pass combination of params into the hash, do what you like with them
  end
end
```

and then, using this pattern, you can pass any combination of params into the constructor:

```
foobar = Foobar.new(:foo => '5', :bar => 10, :baz => 'what?')
```